# How to obtain Franz Ferdinand - Bite Hard synth solo sound

Tags: sound, synthesizer

I am trying to obtain this synth solo sound:

(solo starts at 1:24)

I have a Korg R3 but in the best case I found something just remotely similar in the presets.
I can use all the radias sounds on this little synth but I am not an expert so I have no clues on how to obtain something closer to the original sound.

Are you able to help?
A Korg R3 specific solution would be great but if you don't have it even generic suggestion on how to "build" that sound on any synth would be very welcome.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This sounds like a standard organ patch with a distortion effect applied to it.